# what happens if you delete a category in EE?

Tags: categories

What happens when I delete a category? We have created far too many categories, in a hierarchical list. I want to reduce it from 100 to 15 by deleting the sub-categories. Will the article then default back to the parent category? Or will it be completely detached from any category?

Answer (score 0):

Lets make it simple.

Suppose I have a category named Blog and have sub-categories like Articles, news, magazines. My Tree will look like this:

- Blog

  - Articles
  - News
  - magazines

Now, If I assign any entry to "News" category. Later if I decide to remove "News" category, My entry will still relate to it's parent category **(In this case Blog)**

Deleting category will delete the category from `exp_categories` and `exp_category_field_data`